# variable expansion not happening when importing to Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make, variable-expansion

I have a shell script with some variables w/ variable expansions:

```
$ cat version
#!/bin/bash
export GIT_TAG=`git describe --tags --always --dirty`
export BUILD_NUM=${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER:-${GIT_TAG}}
export VERSION="0.1.${BUILD_NUM}"
```

Then I'm trying to import the variables into a Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables
include version
all:
    @echo $(VERSION)
```

However it seems variable expansion isn't working:

```
$ make
Makefile:5: warning: undefined variable `TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER:-`git describe --tags --always --dirty`'
version:16: warning: undefined variable `TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER:-`git describe --tags --always --dirty`'
version:13: warning: undefined variable `TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER:-`git describe --tags --always --dirty`'
0.1.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `include` file should be a makefile, not a shell script.

Comment: There's a lot written about importing .env files, shell scripts, etc..., in addition to other Makefiles.  And it does work if I don't use variable expansion.  Its only when I start using variable expansion that I'm hitting issues like this.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) says **The include directive tells make to suspend reading the current makefile and read one or more other makefiles before continuing.** It's only able to read the file because `export` is also a `make` command. But make doesn't understand `${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER:-${GIT_TAG}}` as a parameter expansion operation, that's a bash feature.

Comment: @jerseybean try adding other bash commands (i.e. `echo $VERSION`) to the bash script and you will see how it doesn't work

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano oic.. thx for pointing out

Comment: @Barmar so I guess your right.  thx for the response.